# Remove newline \ linefeed before a regex match

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

I'm currently writing a bash script for parsing a simple text file.
I now have the problem that there are a few occurences of new lines, where none should be.
Let me give you an example

```
Q1bcd    3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Ba     Klasse hat Aufgab..
8 a     3    ---        ---     Mr
6 b      3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Bu     Unterricht im
Klassenverband
8 a     4    ---        ---     Ke
7 a      4    De   Bi   r24    La
```

The 'Klassenverband' string is in a new line. I don't want that.
To remove the new line character I tried different commands with sed and awk:

```
awk '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{4\}\)/{printf "%s ",$0;next} 1' file
sed '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{4\}\)/{N;s/\n//;}' file
```

What I've come up with so far, is that all the neccecary strings can be extracted with the following Regex

```
^\([a-zA-Z]\{4\}\)
```

I am expecting an output like this

```
Q1bcd    3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Ba     Klasse hat Aufgab..
8 a     3    ---        ---     Mr
6 b      3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Bu     Unterricht im Klassenverband
8 a     4    ---        ---     Ke
7 a      4    De   Bi   r24    La
```

**Edit:**
This worked for me. But the text file needs to be a unix text file no DOS file

```
sed '$!N; s/\n\([[:alpha:]]\{4,\}\)/ \1/; P;D' file
```

Comment: can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
sed '$!N; s/\n\([[:alpha:]]\{4,\}\)/ \1/; P;D' file
Q1bcd    3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Ba     Klasse hat Aufgab..
8 a     3    ---        ---     Mr
6 b      3 - 4 ---   ---  ---     Bu     Unterricht im Klassenverband
8 a     4    ---        ---     Ke
7 a      4    De   Bi   r24    La
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, assuming the input file is small enough to fit in memory:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n([a-zA-Z]{4})/ $1/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clumsy; there may be a better way

```
awk '{ c=""; if (NR!=1 && !/^[a-zA-Z]{4}/) { c="\n" }; printf("%s%s",c,$0) } END { print "" }'
```

Basically, for each line we print it out *without* the LF character.  Then we can *prefix* the next line with LF, if we don't want to merge this line.

Finally this will mean the last line is miss the final LF, so we add that.